# Install .ipk with usb on webOS TV (without IDE or CLI)

Tags: web-applications, television, webos, lg

I'm currently developing a web application in webOS TV IDE, I've been testing it on the IDE emulator and it works fine.

Now, I need to test it on a real TV, but I'm not able to connect any computer to the TV because the computer and the TV are in different places.

Is there anyway I can install the web app into the TV with a USB-driver?

I have tried to plug in the pen drive directly into the TV but it just showed the media archives.

I have already read [this](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-test/) and installed the Developer Mode App, but I haven't find anyway to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately LG removed any option to run or install applications from the USB (for security reasons). The only way to install an IPK is using the CLI tools (Novacom and Ares) and always activating the development mode first.